# I'm having trouble figuring out which wire should be soldered where

Tags: uart, soldering

I can't figure out which wire I need to solder to which part of the board. I can't find a schematic for this device anywhere. Тhe device is a Parrot MKI9100. This is the display cable.

[image: Parrot MKI9100 display cable]

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a link to information about the ``display cable``. I found [Parrot MKi9100 User guide](https://www.parrot.com/assets/s3fs-public/2021-09/mki9100_user-guide_uk.pdf) but doesn't seem to mention a UART nor display cable.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what a Parrot MKI9100 is and what the cable is connected to? Please [edit] your question to supply all the missing information including the datasheet links for any devices.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it is obvious where the red wire goes ... examine the pads on the end of the wires carefully ... they may each have slightly different shape

Comment: Based upon what @jsotola said is the problem that the cable has been ripped off the pads on the adapter, and the question wants to know which wires in the cable to re-solder? If so can the question be edited accordingly.

Comment: @Adnan1 why is the picture so dark? ... did you not examine the picture after you posted it? ... why is the object of interest only 10% of the picture? ... please redo the picture

Comment: The red wire is the only one which didn't rip the pads off the PCB so that one is obviously 12V. It seems that Tx and Rx are twisted pair:ish? In which case the other cable is GND. Swapping Tx and Rx of an UART is harmless, so you could simply try out both combinations and see which one that works. It would be easy enough to reverse engineer this with a multimeter and whatever sits in the other end of that cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are handy with a DVM it may be easy to determine which wire is the +12 and which is the ground. You would plug the cable into the controller module then check the voltage from each open wire to ground.

If you can positively identify those first two wires the remaining TX and RX wires can be tested one at a time to a possible connection point. When the display does something you've likely found another connection. Then of course the remaining wire goes to the last connection.

If your not handy with a DVM or you just don't want to try that method a simple alternative would be to buy a replacement cable from [here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/276121737751?epid=7034198411&hash=item404a235a17:g:KToAAOSwqN5lHsbb&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA4N3GGPoI%2BY9YQjedL2cMKmp5HHobyQGyOfDHTRTmd1Oc%2BzAt7Exj%2FGaMdmK4BymkhWZsZx5%2BM4Pf65eI7P1K374MwZokFv0ul%2BuOwbwwLrBW2VZ0CJWulcq3jJeTgf43nyMQLpI255Uz%2BgFKOf8gVbJwuLHXq9ZRdHWp64StCsBzi95SXOIb6zGeWfAOGwwMXkkQw1VGfWj6YlfWENz7OOoNwd3gTWt8b3Z9uXCBUk0vaDEPmZAQKFS8Ad20om842tIq1RaO%2Bz3Jt9%2FbgPwTPpbYODT3jzKdsStkFzeErcig%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR6DE2_GFYw) or [here](https://www.vehicle-accessories.net/parrot/parrot-mki9100-display-cable/).